# How to reshape data for a Linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm following the O'Reilly's hands on ML book for the analysis of adult census data.
I have used the same method before on another set and had little problem.
When I run the `lin_reg.fit()` this is what I get:

[image]

This is my X and y:

X:

[image]

```
data = strat_test_set.drop("income", axis=1)
data_labels = strat_train_set["income"].copy()
```

y:

[image]

```
data_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(data)
```

Comment: Can you type the code instead of pictures

Comment: @StupidWolf 
--> 549                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    550             # If input is 1D raise error
    551             if array.ndim == 1:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=data_prepared.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're mistaking X for y and vice versa. X is the data you're predicting from, and y is the data you're trying to predict.

X is likely to have more than one column (multiple features), thus it is marked with an uppercase letter (convention for marking matrices).

y only has one column and is thus a one-dimensional vector, thus it is marked with a lowercase letter (convention for marking vectors).

Your `data_labels` is your y, while your `data_prepared` is your X, however in your code (and in this question) you have them flipped.

Scikit-learn convention for its `fit` method is `fit(X,y)`, where you currently have `fit(y,X)`, so you might want to try `lin_reg.fit(data_prepared, data_labels)`.

However, there might be cases where you have a vector for your X instead of a matrix, in which case you would need to reshape your data according to the error given (array.reshape(-1,1) if you have only a single feature, or array.reshape(1,-1) if you only have a single sample).

Comment: Oh! Thanks!!how do I reshape this though? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @emilie579 if you have a `numpy.array` called `y`, you'd have to do `y = y.reshape(1,-1)` or `y = y.reshape(-1,1)`. If you start of from pandas Series, you'd need to first convert it to a `numpy.array` via `y  = y.values`, then reshape it. If you start of with a simple python list, you'd also need to convert it to `numpy.array` first as `y = np.array(y)` then reshape it.